# module.exports error for webpack backend (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use webpack to bundle my backend code. It's currently using vanilla node.js where I'm using `module.exports.x`, and when I run webpack, it also outputs the export line i.e. `module.exports.x`. Now the problem is when I run nodemon on the file, it gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined`.

What's my resolution here?

my config file.

```
"use strict"
const path = require("path")
// const utils = require("./utils")
// const config = require("../config")
var fs = require("fs")
const NodemonPlugin = require("nodemon-webpack-plugin")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

function resolve(dir) 
{
    return path.join(__dirname, "..", dir)
}

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    entry: "./src/server/server.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/server"),
        filename: "server-webpack.js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodemonPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js",".ts", ".tsx"],
        alias: {
            "@": resolve("src"),
            "#": resolve("src/server")
        }
    },
    devtool: "#inline-source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: [resolve("src"), resolve("test")]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
            },
        ]
    },
    externals: [
        nodeExternals()
    ],
    target: "node"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3719   somewhat related if u are mixing both 'import' & module.exports  u will get an undef error

Comment: @RobertRowntree nah, I'm not mixing import and module.exports (since node doesn't know what import means), I was just using require. I'll just delete the module.exports rows instead